# Call another javascript function when a functions is not respondong

Tags: javascript

I have two javascript functions

```
searchButtonClicked()
hidemap()
```

The `searchButtonClicked()` will be called in `body onload`.

The `searchButtonClicked()` sometimes not respond. So I want to let it try to execute for 5 seconds and if it dosent execute I want to call `hidemap()`.

Please help. Thanks in advance.
Udy

here is the function

```
function searchButtonClicked() {
    if (inlocatorHubMode) {
    locatorHubSearch();
    }
    else {
    search();
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `searchButtonClicked` do internally? Ajax?

Comment: it search data from an external service and return a array of results.

Comment: You should look into why sometimes searchButtonClicked() does not respond rather than loading another function on fail.

Comment: So please show us that function. Otherwise we can't help you

Comment: @Jehanzeb.Malik it is actually not in my scope. I just get a result from the function. What I need to do is, i must allow it to execute for several seconds and if not, call another function.

Comment: That means in your functions somewhere the script is breaking. This in turn causes the js to break. You need to use try catch to prevent this for happening. Do you see any error in console of developer tools when the js crashes?

Comment: no. I'm waiting for an external service to return an array of values to my function. Sometimes that service not respond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming searchButtonClicked is an AJAX request.

If this is the case, you can achieve what you're after using a combination of setTimeout and a callback.

```
var searchTimeout = null;

function searchButtonClicked(){
  searchTimeout = setTimeout(requestFailed, 5000);

  //If you're using jQuery, something like this
  $.ajax({
    url: "service.php",
    success: requestSuccess
  });

  //If you're not, something like this
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=(function(){
    if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
      requestSuccess();
    }
  });  
}

function requestSuccess(){
  clearTimeout(searchTimeout);
  //Yay! It succeeded!
}

function requestFailed(){
  hideMap();
  //It didn't unfortunately =[
}
```

**Edit:** An edit was made to say that it's not in fact an AJAX request. Leaving this here in case it's useful to somebody.

Comment: thank you for the answer @Dolondro. But my function doesn't have an Ajax call. I added the function to my question. Please have a look at it. Again, your help is much appreciated.

Comment: how can I set a waiting time to this?? like 5 sec

Comment: Oops, the setTimeout should have read `setTimeout(requestFailed, 5000)` to signify that it'd last 5 seconds. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

There is a function in javascript

```
window.setTimeout("javascript function",milliseconds);
```

This functions waits the specified number of milliseconds, and then executes the specified function.

In your case you can set timeout at the beginning of your function.
So that after the specified milliseconds, your second function will execute